# C++ char* array

Tags: c++

When I create something like

```
char* t = new char[44];
t = strcpy(s,t);
```

then `strlen(t);` return some wrong results. how I can change this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `strcpy` and `strlen` expect to find the special character `NUL` or `'\0'` in the array. An uninitialized array, as the one you've created, may contain anything at all, which means the behavior of your program is undefined when it is passed to `strcpy` as the source argument.

Assuming the goal was to copy `s` into `t`, to make the program behave as expected, try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
int main()
{
    const char* s = "test string";
    char* t = new char[44];
//  std::strcpy(t, s); // t is the destination, s is the source!
    std::strncpy(t, s, 44); // you know the size of the target, use it
    std::cout << "length of the C-string in t is " << std::strlen(t) << '\n';
    delete[] t;
}
```

But keep in mind that in C++, strings are handled as objects of type `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    const std::string s = "test string";
    std::string t = s;
    std::cout << "length of the string in t is " << t.size() << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do? Do you want to copy from `s` to `t`? If so, the arguments to `strcpy` are reversed.

```
char* t = new char[44]; // allocate a buffer
strcpy(t,s); // populate it
```

Such C-style string processing is a red flag, but that's all I can say given this little information.

Answer (score 1):

This code might be helpful:

```
char * strcpy (char * destination, const char * source);
t = strcpy(t, s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the variable `t`

Do something like this:

```
char *t = new char[44];
memset(t, 0, 44);

// strlen(t) = 0
```

Comment: Or by using `char* t = new char[44]();`, you can get rid of the memset.

Answer (score 0):

The `strcpy` function [is described](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) thus:

```
#include <string.h>
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

> The strcpy() function copies the string pointed to by `src` (including the terminating '\0' character) to the array pointed to by `dest`.

So, if you are trying to fill in your newly allocated array, you should be doing:

```
strcpy(t, s);
```

Not the other way around.